# Doctrine2 native query hydrator error in 'as'

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i want use native query using 'as' clause to set class attribute:

```
public function findIntersects($id,$pontos){

$em = $this->getEntityManager();

 $sql = "SELECT p.imovel,p.id,ST_Area(ST_Intersection(p.location,'POLYGON((".$pontos."))')) as area_int, ST_Area(p.location) as area from propriedades p where ST_Intersects(p.location,'POLYGON((".$pontos."))') and id !=:id";

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Incra\PropriedadesBundle\Entity\Propriedades', 'o');
$rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'imovel', 'imovel');
$rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'area_int', 'area_int');
$rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'area', 'area');

 $qns = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$qns->setParameter("id", $id);
$qns->setParameter("pontos", $pontos);


  return $qns->getResult();


}
```

i have this attributes in my class but dont have annotations of orm

and i get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: area_int in
>   /var/www/incra/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php
>   line 205

my class: http://pastebin.com/jd3gcr93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used executeQuery to use native without dql

Answer (score 0):

You haven't marked `area_int` as a data column (line 120 in your class). Since you've listed `area_int` in field results (`$rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'area_int', 'area_int');`) Doctrine tries to map the column to the entity, but can't find it. Try modifying your class with

```
/**@ORM\Column(name="area_int", type="int")*/
private $area_int;
```

Also, just for the sake of security/performance/goo code style/etc. You are directly injecting `$pontos` in the query string. This makes your code subject to SQL injections. Later, you add `$pontos` as a parameter. This two approaches are redundant so you'd better remove one of them. I would definitely try to use parameter approach, so your query becomes something like

```
SELECT p.imovel,p.id,ST_Area(ST_Intersection(p.location,'POLYGON((:pontos))')) as area_int, 
       ST_Area(p.location) as area from propriedades p 
where ST_Intersects(p.location,'POLYGON((:pontos))') and id !=:id
```

In case it would not work you may remove `$qns->setParameter("pontos", $pontos);`, but then you are ought to perform as much sanity checks and validations as possible to prevent SQL-injections.

Comment: but 'area_int' dont is a column in the database table, is a return of a psql function, i dont want make this a column. i know of $pontos, but this value getted directly the database and are verifield inserted